# Get item of actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to get a reference to an item in my actionbar. I want to access it in `onCreate`

```
    int silent_mode = SupportFunctions.getSharedPreferenceInt(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.shared_preferences_name), "silent_mode", 0);
    Item item = // getItem?
    if (silent_mode == 1) {
        item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_silent_mode_on));
    }
    else {
        item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_silent_mode_off));
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the work in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` instead, then it will be accessable:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ...


    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.YOUR_ID);
    int silent_mode = SupportFunctions.getSharedPreferenceInt(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.shared_preferences_name), "silent_mode", 0);
    if (silent_mode == 1) {
        item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_silent_mode_on));
    }
    else {
        item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_silent_mode_off));
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: thanks!!!! that works. the issue really was that i could not use mnMenu in onCreate!

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` store the reference of the menu in a class-level variable. Like this:

```
Menu mnMenu;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ....
    ....
    mnMenu = menu;
    return true;   
}

private void someMethod() {
    int silent_mode = SupportFunctions.getSharedPreferenceInt(getApplicationContext(),   getResources().getString(R.string.shared_preferences_name), "silent_mode", 0);
    MenuItem item = mnMenu.findItem(R.id.action) //R.id.action is the id of your MenuItem
    if (silent_mode == 1) {
        item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_silent_mode_on));
    }
    else {
        item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_silent_mode_off));
    }
}
```

Comment: (; forgot to, sorry. can you tell me why the prefix "mn" is often used to demonstrate things? like mnMenu?

Comment: It's just a way of knowing of what type the object is (atleast, I use it for that). In a huge program there may be many lines of code so to see the type of data held in a particular object you may have to scroll up and down to see of which type that object is. But by prefixing them with such characters we can easily know (or recall) of what type that object is

Comment: For example, I use "str" for `String`, "tv" for `TextView`, "et" for `EditText`, "lv" for `ListView`. You can name your own; it doesn't matter at all :)

Comment: okay thanks. can you please edit your answer so it says `MenuItem item` instead of `Item item`. otherwise its wrong!

Comment: Is it a Null Pointer Exception?

Comment: the debugger says `ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2295`

Comment: Actually that's the "error log" I am talking about. Why don't you ask another question posting the error log? And by error log I mean all the "red lines" that appear after this statement

Comment: Of course it worked! In fact this is the way I have used in all my apps. So I think it's a different problem buddy. Now let's stop wasting comment space here and post a new question

Comment: okay i have one last idea before i create a new question. how can I log what my Menu-variable is? `Log.e("TEST", mnMenu.toString());` ? I think its not created at the time i wanna use it

Comment: Whoa buddy, just look up whether in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` you are `mnMenu = menu` after `getMenuInflater().inflate()` or before `getMenuInflater().inflate()`. It should be AFTER!

Comment: well, I'm trying to use menu in onCreate and I wonder whether it's already initialized. onCreateOptionsMenu might be called after onCreate, don't you think? Maybe that's the issue. no need for a new question. so any way to log what mnMenu is? I guess its null.

Comment: thats the issue. i tested it with toasts. onCreate is called before onCreateOptionsMenu is, so in onCreate my mnMenu is null! Thats the issue.

Comment: Yes Phillip. Important lesson- `onCreate()` --> `onResume()` --> `onCreateOptionsMenu()` always remember